# How to pass a JSON file to a AWS Lambda through an API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda running on AWS that processes a JSON file. I'd like to pass that JSON file from the command line using `curl` through a REST interface configured on an API gateway, e.g.

```
curl -X POST -H "x-api-key: MyAPIKey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @myFile.json https://my-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/MyLambda
```

I've created an API gateway, and added it as a trigger for the lambda, but when the request method is triggered, the content of the JSON file has been added to the "body" attribute of a JSON object.

Is it possible to pass the file directly to the lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the request in the event.body, it implies that you are using the Lambda Proxy integration.

[image]

What you are looking for is known as non-proxy integration or Custom Integration. More details on how to set that up [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html). Uncheck this option. Then you will have to configure the request and response mapping templates.

If the json looks like the following -

```
{
  "attr1": "v1",
  "attr2": "v2"
}
```

then your mapping template for application/json will look like this -

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "attr1": "$inputRoot.attr1",
  "attr2": "$inputRoot.attr2",
}
```

Then in the Lambda function, attributes can directly be accessed as event.attr1, event.attr2 etc.

Then you can use the same cURL command to call the API Gateway.